# Sbt: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git"

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

Git path is properly set in IntelliJ settings. And intelliJ is able to use git just fine. However, importing a SBT project fails with the error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ delegates the import process to SBT which uses the system PATH variable to find git. So even if git is configured properly in IntelliJ SBT will not find it unless it is on PATH.

Configured PATH and restarted IntelliJ. SBT import worked this time

Comment: @ankitsuthar See this [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/184948). The purpose is to save the next guy 10 minutes that I spent debugging the problem